# Django #hashtags in url

Tags: css, django

Sooo what am trying to do is a link on CONTACT to redirect to HOME and scroll down to some content, but dont know how to pass # in urls in django. Any help appreciated. The scroll is fine on home but cant get it to work from contact.

URL

```
path('/#products', HomeView.as_view(), name='products'),
```

CONTACT.html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:products' %}">Products</a>
```

HOME.html

this is in navbar

```
<a class="nav-link" style="cursor: pointer" href='#products'>Products</a>
```

this is where i want it scrolled

```
<a class="anchor" id="products"></a>
```

Comment: you do not need to put `#products` in urls.py. Just putting #products in browser will send you to that id in a page if `products` id exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RedirectView** for this:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import reverse

class ViewpostRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs):
        hash_part = "add_data_Modal"  # the data you want to add to the hash part
        return reverse("createpost") + "#{0}".format(hash_part)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('viewpost/', views.createpost, name='createpost'),
path('viewpost/modal/', views.ViewpostRedirectView.as_view(), name='createpost_modal')
```

More info : https://www.kite.com/python/docs/django.views.generic.RedirectView